# get-process for a specific process off a list of machines returns the same result over and over

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

I have a confusing issue here. I have created a script that checks a bunch of machines for a running instance of JAVAW.

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\computers.txt  
foreach ($computer in $computers){  
    Get-Process -ComputerName $computers -Name Javaw | select machinename, id, ProcessName  
}
```

It certainly finds the JAVAW process running on some of the machines (as expected) in the TXT file but repeats the results in some kind of loop. I would have expected it to only report each machine that's running JAVAW once. Its not reporting different instances of JAVAW on the same machines either, the PID is the same. So for example on one machine it reports JAVAW PID 1612 5 times.

So the output looks like this:

computer1  1612 javaw
computer2  1964 javaw
computer3  8448 javaw
computer1  1612 javaw
computer2  1964 javaw
computer3  8448 javaw
computer1  1612 javaw
computer2  1964 javaw
computer3  8448 javaw
etc
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're scanning every computer `X` times, where `X` is the number of computers you in `computers.txt`.

- `Get-Process`'s `-Computername` parameter accepts a *collection* of computer names and when you pass it a collection, it pulls the process list for each of those computers. You're passing `$computers` but you meant to pass `$computer` - the "iterator" for each time through the loop.
- You're looping through the list of computers in `computers.txt` once per computer.

Choose one or the other - the `foreach` loop, or passing `$computers` to `get-process`.

Option 1 (my preference):

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\computers.txt;
Get-Process -ComputerName $computers -Name Javaw | select machinename, id, ProcessName;
```

Option 1a:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName $(get-content c:\computers.txt) -Name Javaw | select machinename, id, ProcessName;
```

Option 2:

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\computers.txt; 
foreach ($computer in $computers){  
    Get-Process -ComputerName $computer -Name Javaw | select machinename, id, ProcessName;
}
```

Option 3:

```
Get-Content C:\computers.txt | foreach-object {Get-Process -ComputerName $_ -Name Javaw | select machinename, id, ProcessName};
```

Comment: Hi alroc, thanks very much I opted for your option 2 which works perfectly. I now understand what I was doing wrong, thank you for the explanation too!

Comment: @lanB: Accepting the answer would be appreciable